# Android how add cyrillic symbol in exif file

Tags: android, exif

How add cyrillic symbol in exif file?
My code alwais added symbol "?".
This code:

```
String userComment = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛСНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
exifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", userComment );
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

or

```
String userComment = "АБВГДЕЁЖЗИЙКЛСНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯ";
exifInterface.setAttribute("UserComment", new String(userComment.getBytes(), "UTF-8"));
exifInterface.saveAttributes();
```

Comment: Dont know if it is possible. Have you ever seen a jpg file with an exif info with cyrillic chars? If so then please put it on the internet and give an url to it.

Comment: How do you check the result? With your app or an external app?

Comment: I checked the result in my application and external application.

Comment: Please define your charSequence variable in your post with cyrillic content.

Comment: Can you use chars that do NOT look like latin ones? A decent text please! Like: This is me on de Wolga river.

Comment: Wrong translation! Now i'm waiting for an url. You know that.

Comment: I specified the Russian alphabet as an example of the initialization of charSequence.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/bkaa0uhd95zwr2l/image.jpeg?dl=0
In file tag usercomment have cyrillic symbols.

Comment: What is the solution for this task?

Comment: My code not showing this symbols. It showing symbols "?". External app showing this symbols correct.

Comment: In the photo on the link above I added a UserComment tag in a external application.

Comment: This my code:

String userComment = exifInterface.getAttribute("UserComment");
textView.setText(userComment);

Answer (score 0):

Think that ExifInterface class does not support this cyrillic.

I tried to get the bytes from that tag with

```
    byte [] bytes1 = exifInterface.getAttribute("UserComment").getBytes();
    byte [] bytes2 = exifInterface.getAttribute("UserComment").getBytes("utf-8");
//  byte [] bytes3 = exifInterface.getAttribute("UserComment").getBytes("utf-16");
//  byte [] bytes3 = exifInterface.getAttribute("UserComment").getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
    byte [] bytes3 = exifInterface.getAttribute("UserComment").getBytes("windows-1252");
```

And then displayed the bytes in hexadecimal notation. They were all rubbish.

There were 66  bytes for your 33 characters. Dont know which encoding is used.

I wanted to compare them with the bytes of your alphabet string.

Also tried compiling for Andoid 7 but all the same.

I give up ;-).

Comment: No. If i cannot read the exif then i will not try to write an exif. How would i check the write? Only with external app.

Comment: Try a different exif interface class. There is. Google for it.

Answer (score 0):

"UserComment" tag in Exif support ASCII or Unicode.

Unfortunately, Android's ExifInterface only use ASCII to write or read the tag.

So, cyrillic symbol is not support by Android's ExifInterface.

But this lib may help you:

https://github.com/ddyos/UnicodeExifInterface